# How to sum up two Scope values in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, function, sum, operators

```
var selPage2 = $scope.selPage + $scope.itemsPerPage;
$scope.selPageUp = selPage2;
```

for example if value of selPage is 50 and value of itemsPerPage is 10 and I want to display my value in HTML element like

```
{{selPageUp}}
```

Angular JS will make connection of this two strings and will display it like 5010, but I want to sum up two values to display number 60. How to do that? Example if I change operator from + to * it will multiply value and display 500 it will work on way I want. Help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are integers:

```
var selPage2 = parseInt($scope.selPage) + parseInt($scope.itemsPerPage);
```

Otherwise:

```
var selPage2 = parseFloat($scope.selPage) + parseFloat($scope.itemsPerPage);
```

Comment: not work for my case

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope.selpage` and `$scope.itemPerPage` are probably of type String. if they would be Integers it would sum up fine. so first you have to convert this string to an Integer of Float with `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`. 2 Strings do multiply because `*` is a Math function so it will automatically TRY to convert these strings in values.